# c# deserialization exception InvalidOperationException: <ArrayOf xmlns=''> was not expected. How to import array from XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a list that contains instances of my class (Trade). I am trying to save the data to an xml so I can reload if program crashes. I think I have the saving part down, but am struggling to reload the data into a usable format.

```
    public class Trade
    {
        public int TradeID { get; set; }
        public int OrderSize { get; set; }
        public string TradeSide { get; set; }
        public string EntryOrderId { get; set; }
        public string EntryOrderStatus { get; set; }
        public decimal EntryOrderPrice { get; set; }
        public string ExitOrderId { get; set; }
        public string ExitOrderStatus { get; set; }
        public decimal ExitOrderPrice { get; set; }
        public string TradeStatus { get; set; }
        public int TargetPoints { get; set; }//points in miniimum movement (currently .5)
        public string TimeElapsed { get; set; }//time since entry, possibly change later
        public string CancelCondition { get; set; }
        public bool RateType { get; set; }//Market or Specified (for recording purposes)
    }
```

My current xml data file

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfTrade xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Trade>
    <TradeID>1</TradeID>
    <OrderSize>100</OrderSize>
    <TradeSide>Sell</TradeSide>
    <EntryOrderId>417705ed-4413-5436-01be-280e9aab0e6d</EntryOrderId>
    <EntryOrderStatus>New</EntryOrderStatus>
    <EntryOrderPrice>8005.5</EntryOrderPrice>
    <ExitOrderId />
    <ExitOrderStatus />
    <ExitOrderPrice>0</ExitOrderPrice>
    <TradeStatus>Created</TradeStatus>
    <TargetPoints>1</TargetPoints>
    <TimeElapsed />
    <CancelCondition>Test condition</CancelCondition>
    <RateType>true</RateType>
  </Trade>
  <Trade>
    <TradeID>2</TradeID>
    <OrderSize>100</OrderSize>
    <TradeSide>Buy</TradeSide>
    <EntryOrderId>ba834f62-c014-df2d-2e20-ec7713a8ac09</EntryOrderId>
    <EntryOrderStatus>New</EntryOrderStatus>
    <EntryOrderPrice>700</EntryOrderPrice>
    <ExitOrderId />
    <ExitOrderStatus />
    <ExitOrderPrice>0</ExitOrderPrice>
    <TradeStatus>Created</TradeStatus>
    <TargetPoints>1</TargetPoints>
    <TimeElapsed />
    <CancelCondition>Test condition</CancelCondition>
    <RateType>true</RateType>
  </Trade>
</ArrayOfTrade>
```

That was generated from my save function. I passed a list of List TradesList to it.

```
     private void SaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = @"C:\Users\bkenn\Documents\AT Project\TradeHistory\ZTTrades.txt";//
        Save(ZTTrades, file);//
    }

    public static void Save<T>(T ToSerialize, string FileSpec)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(FileSpec.Substring(0, FileSpec.LastIndexOf('\\')));
        FileStream outFile = File.Create(FileSpec);
        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        formatter.Serialize(outFile, ToSerialize);
    }
```

My issue is with my loading code. From reading the forums and docs Ive come up with the following code.

```
    [XmlRootAttribute("Trades")]
        public class TradeCollection
        {
            [XmlElement("Trade")]
            public Trade[] TradeA { get; set; }
        }
        static TradeCollection XTrade()
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Users\bkenn\Documents\AT Project\TradeHistory\ZTTrades.txt";//

            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TradeCollection));
                return (TradeCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
```

To process the load.

```
    c = XTrade();//

            foreach (var k in c.TradeA)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k.TradeID + "" + k.EntryOrderId + "");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Which is where I get the error

> "InvalidOperationException:  was not expected."

I believe I am on the right track. My end goal is to repopulate TradesList so my program can run as normal.

Any help is much appreciated. I am new to c#, most functions have come easy to me but reading through this XML information is difficult, it always seems like someone has their own way of doing it. I am just looking for one that works for my application.

Comment: What type is `ZTTrades`?  You should just be able to use that type when you deserialize.

Comment: Sorry, I changed variable names midway ZTTrades is a list of type Trade. I also labeled it as TradesList

Answer (score 2):

I just ran through your code and everything works fine when you change one litte thing.

```
    [XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfTrade")]
    public class TradeCollection
    {
        [XmlElement("Trade")]
        public Trade[] TradeA { get; set; }
    }
```

The XML document you have, its root element is `ArrayOfTrade,` not **Trades**. Changing that made your code work like its supposed to with the following output

```
1417705ed-4413-5436-01be-280e9aab0e6d
2ba834f62-c014-df2d-2e20-ec7713a8ac09
```

Comment: I will try that, thanks!